# org.plasma.query.OrderBy not working

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, hbase

New to java,I am using org.plasma.query.dsl.domainroot.orderby(dataproperty)
but its not giving me the correct answer.
    For examples

```
Qxxx xxx = new Qxxx.newquery();
xxx.select(xxx.wildcard());
xxx.orderby(xxx.no_of_hates()); //orderby no_of_hates(datafields)
```

This query for getting xxx in a sorted order by no_of_hates and also tried this

```
xxx.orderby(xxx.no_of_hates().desc());
```

but giving wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hovercraft and Gaurav, this problem is fixed in plasma 1.1.6 and was rolled into issue 18. See  https://github.com/terrameta/plasma/issues/18
Very sorry for the long delay !!